# Google Maps Business Priority

Tags: google-maps

https://www.google.com/maps/place/3000+Boulevard+Fr%C3%A9chette,+Chambly,+QC+J3L+6Z6,+Canada/@45.4313885,-73.3028823,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4cc9a7e6dfe11bd1:0x4438d7c6043d5d57?hl=fr-FR

I'm having some trouble figuring out something with google maps.

At the location given, while zoomed out you'll see nothing. Then, if you zoom in, the business Isatis Sport Chambly will be shown.

But then you need 7 more ticks zooming forward to show the Restaurant associated with the business (Le caucus)

I was wondering, is there any way to make a Google My Business point have a higher priority on the map (so for instance, the point will be shown while zoomed out a little more)?

I guess this can't be changed. But if it can't be changed, what are the conditions for a business to be shown or not at particular zoom levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How far out the Place Label will be visible is something you don't have control over. I think you should read the following [link](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6056435?hl=en)

Basically depends on factors like

- ["Verifying your business"](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778)
- Completing your Google+ Local profile
- The Prominence of your business compared with others in your area.

among others.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on a number of factors, here is a good starting point.https://moz.com/community/q/different-zoom-levels-of-spots-in-google-maps